# Azure media services: Customize ContentKey authorization policy based on backend data

Tags: azure-media-services

I've not been able to find decent information in the docs for this.  Here's to the internet :)

This is my current understanding:

The documented approach is to create a ContentKeyPolicy with JWT restriction and Media Services will expect the claim added to the token of `urn:microsoft:azure:mediaservices:contentkeyidentifier=INJECTED CONTENT KEY ID HERE` based on what content the locator URL is serving up.

This means I'd need a new content key for every SKU sold to secure access to the media.  Is there a way to hook into this authorization logic to say "I want you to call this API to run my custom validation" where I could check the JWT user's purchased content?  This way only one content policy is really needed and becomes manageable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom scenario you described is exactly the reason for using unique content key identifiers.

The way the key delivery server works with JWT tokens is that the key delivery server first checks to see which content key ID is being used.  It then checks to see if the token is properly signed with the primary verification key that was used for that locator.  Then it validates any claims that were applied when the encryption policies were set.

I'd recommend tracking the primary verification key (if unique per locator), the locator itself, the content key ID, and any claims in your own database so that all of those values are readily accessible for any of your content.

Comment: Thank you for helping!  I guess my concern is adding more and more content key id values into the claim.  With more and more skus, it seems odd that its "expected" that it gets fatter in size.

Do you add multiple content key ids as a claim array or comma sep?

Comment: You'd only use one content key ID per token.  Each token should be unique to that specific client / session.  We also generally recommend that the token be valid for +5 minutes and -5 minutes from "now" at the time it is issued.  Technically you could make the token valid only for a few seconds, but that +-5 minutes is to handle clock drift between your token delivery server and the AMS key delivery server.

Comment: I guess where I am hung up is, what if i want about 100 separate assets under a single claim?  When our customer purchases, they are buying essentially an album, not a single file.   Are you saying I should maintain my own lookup, and then if they want to play track 1, generate a token for track 1, separate token for track 2, etc?  Is there no way to have all the tracks roll up into the same required claim?